# How to specifically tell xdotools which libreoffice window it should use

Tags: raspbian-buster

i have the problem that i want to get a libreoffice impress presentation with windowactivate.
The Problem is that its always switching between the actual slideshow and the libreoffice software.
Can i somehow specify that xdotool can only access the slideshow. I need that because the presentation
is auto opened at the start. So it should be something that is at every start of the raspberry the same

Answer (score 1):

You can access a particular window using `xdotool` [window stack](https://www.linux.org/threads/xdotool-%E2%80%93-window-stack.10687/). Try

```
xdotool search --class libreoffice getwindowname %@
```

and see if your slideshow window is listed. You can then send commands specifically to this window by ID.